# Java for loop in Python example

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have in java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++ ){
        System.out.println("i = " + i + "******");
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("j = " + j + " ");
        }

    }
```

with output:

```
run:
i = 0******
j = 0 i = 1******
j = 0 j = 1 i = 2******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 i = 3******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 i = 4******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 i = 5******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 i = 6******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 i = 7******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 i = 8******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 i = 9******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 j = 9 i = 10******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 j = 9 j = 10
```

I'd like to achieve exactly effect in python for loop:

```
x = 10

for i in range(0, x, 1):
    print("i = ", i, "*******")
    for j in range(0, i, 1):
        print("j = ", j, end="")
```

Output:

```
i =  0 *******
i =  1 *******
j =  0i =  2 *******
j =  0j =  1i =  3 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2i =  4 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3i =  5 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3j =  4i =  6 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3j =  4j =  5i =  7 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3j =  4j =  5j =  6i =  8 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3j =  4j =  5j =  6j =  7i =  9 *******
j =  0j =  1j =  2j =  3j =  4j =  5j =  6j =  7j =  8
```

I started learning python, I know java at intermediate level and cant start thinking in those pyhon loops. Python 3.6

Comment: `sep="",end=" "` should work in your case. Default separation between arguments `sep` is set to `" "`. Python `range` doesnt include end value, so loops would have to go to `x+1` and `i+1`

Answer (score 7):

The **upper bound of `range(..)` is exclusive**, so you simply need to **add one to the upper bound**:

```
x = 10

for i in range(0, x+1):
    print("i = ",i,"*******",sep='')
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print("j = ",j, sep='', end=' ')
```

If the step is `1`, you do not have to mention this. By default Python uses 1 as step.

Furthermore by default Python will *separate* two arguments with a space, you can use the `sep` parameter to split it with no space (or another character sequence).

This prints:

```
i = 0*******
j = 0 i = 1*******
j = 0 j = 1 i = 2*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 i = 3*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 i = 4*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 i = 5*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 i = 6*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 i = 7*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 i = 8*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 i = 9*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 j = 9 i = 10*******
j = 0 j = 1 j = 2 j = 3 j = 4 j = 5 j = 6 j = 7 j = 8 j = 9 j = 10
```

Comment: Thank you, i got it now.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `end=" "` rather than `end=""` to have a space between a value of `j` and the string `j =` from next iteration.
Besides, the result of `range` does **not** include the upper limit, you have to add 1 to compensate for it. 
And finally, instead of:

```
print("i = ", i, "*******")
```

use

```
print("i = {}*******".format(i))
```

to exactly reproduce your Java output.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution of your problem.

```
x=10
for i in range(0,x+1):
print "i = "+str(i)+"******"
for j in range(0,i+1):
    print "j = "+str(j)+" ",
```

output:-

```
i = 0******
j = 0  i = 1******
j = 0  j = 1  i = 2******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  i = 3******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  i = 4******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  i = 5******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  i = 6******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  j = 6  i = 7******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  j = 6  j = 7  i = 8******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  j = 6  j = 7  j = 8  i = 9******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  j = 6  j = 7  j = 8  j = 9  i = 10******
j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3  j = 4  j = 5  j = 6  j = 7  j = 8  j = 9  j = 10
```